# Should one use separate samples for factor analysis and for the analysis the follows (regression etc.)

Tags: factor-analysis

If I need to run factor analysis, and the regression with the factors obtained as variables, should I split the sample into two groups and conduct factor analysis on one and regression on the other? what des the theory say, and what do people do if the sample is not big enough?

Thank!